# Keyboard hook w/ C# and WPF for minimized system tray application

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, hook

I have a WPF application that I minimize to the system tray through this.Hide() and System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.  When it's minimized, I want to have a keyboard hook maximize the application.  How do I register a keyboard hook like Windows-Button & T, for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind Win32 API calls, I'd say your best bet is to call [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx). You pass it the modifier and key to catch, then a `WM_HOTKEY` is sent to the HWND that you passed in originally.